# sender() pointing to dead letter for the message from actor system

Tags: akka, actor

Please look at the below code and explain why my output is pointing to deadLetters.

```scala
class DemoActor extends  Actor {
  def receive = {
    case "foo" => println(sender())
  }
}


object Main extends App {
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("DemoSystem")
  val demoActorRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[DemoActor])
  demoActorRef ! "foo"
}
```

Output:

```scala
Actor[akka://DemoSystem/deadLetters]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Surely it's because you're not calling it from another actor, so therefore there's nowhere to reply to? (therefore it wouldn't be sensible to have a sender)

Comment: So only when an actor B is called from another actor A, the sender() will be actor A. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the actor system doesn't have a mailbox that replies could be posted to.

The Sender reference is used for sending replies without the contacted actor needing to know who called it, as well as the ask mechanism.

You can see this in practice by trying the same call from another actor vs the system, and you'll see the sender reference is valid when called from another actor.